# ckecking and unchecking checkbox in dat.gui

Tags: javascript, checkbox, three.js, dat.gui

I have a checkbox named autorotation.I want to mark that checkbox to false when user click any where in the scene...

```
controller = new function() {  
    this.autorotation=true;
}
var gui = new dat.GUI();
f1 = gui.addFolder('Sphere');
autorotation=controller.autorotation;
q=f1.add(controller, 'autorotation').listen().onChange( function()
{
    autorotation=controller.autorotation;

});

function onDocumentMouseDown(event)
{
    controller.autorotation=false;
    //stop autorotation and uncheck the box.
    //user may check the box for rotation manually by clicking on checkbox.
}
```

This code works.I want to mark uncheck through code.Controller.autorotation=false mark check box to false but does not stops auto rotation.If i stop rotation by autorotation=false.Then i have to click two times on checkbox to check it to true

Comment: It still doesn't explain some things. What element the `onDocumentMouseDown` event handler added to? Also there's no code related to Three.js, thus it's hard to understand what `autorotation` does and what it's involved into.

Answer (score 0):

Your code works fine. You just didn't add an event listener to an object you want to get clicks.

Just for example, I added a canvas element and added the `onDocumentMouseDown` on its mouse down event.

From my point of view, there's no need to have that `autorotation` variable, as you already have `contorller.autorotation`, which you can easily to refer to.

```js
controller = new function() {  
    this.autorotation=true;
}
var gui = new dat.GUI();
f1 = gui.addFolder('Sphere');
q=f1.add(controller, 'autorotation').listen().onChange( function()
{
    autorotation=controller.autorotation;

});

scene.addEventListener("mousedown", onDocumentMouseDown, false);
function onDocumentMouseDown(event)
{
    controller.autorotation=false;
    //stop autorotation and uncheck the box.
    //user may check the box for rotation manually by clicking on checkbox.
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/dat-gui/0.6.5/dat.gui.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="scene" style="border:1px solid red;background-color:aqua;"></canvas>
```

Comment: There is slightly misunderstanding in question.This code works.I want to mark uncheck through code.Controller.autorotation=false mark check box to false but does not stops auto rotation.If i stop rotation by autorotation=false.Then i have to click two times on checkbox to check it to true.

Comment: @AbdulAhad So you should post full code with clearer explanation of the problem. As from your question it means that the problem is marking the checkbox and nothing about the other stuff you've just explained in the comment to my answer.